# import text file to SQL Server 2008 Database real time

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, logging

I have a machine which creates a new log file at the beginning of the day(12am) and updates  the log file whenever there is any changes until the end of the day.

1. How do I import the data in real time (30 sec, 1min or whenever there is any changes) to my SQL server database?
2. Will SQL Server 2008 be able to access the active log file? If not will it be easier if i let my machine create a new log file whenever there is any updates? But if it is so, how do i import so many log files with different names in real time. ( I must be able to scale the solution up to multiple machines)

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can log each new line with a reversed time stamp.

Since you need to log only when the file changes you can implement an in memory queue
which reads from the file and stores the data.
Then implement a producer consumer model wherein one thread reads and loads data from the queue and the consumer logs to the database.
A windows service then can keep reading from the queue and log to the SQL Server.
(Since it's a producer consumer there will not be any busy waiting in case the queue is empty)

Somehow you will also have to notify the producer thread whenever every log is made. This can be done through Sockets/or some other means in case you have access to the code which is doing the logging.

Comment: what if i dont have access to the code which is doing the logging. The machine is maintained by 3rd party

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the application producing the file then you have little option but to poll the file.  Write an application that regularly polls the file and writes the deltas to the database.  The application will need to record a high water mark that it has last read to.

Another wrinkle is that if the application does not close the file between writes then the last accessed time stamp might not be updated, so checking the age of the file may not be reliable.  In this case you need to implement something like this process:

- Open the log file
- Seek to your last recorded EOF position
- Try reading
- If successful, process the new data until you get to the new EOF.
- Update your persistent EOF position
- Close the file

You will need to make sure that the number of bytes read aligns with your file seek position.  If the log file is unicode then it may not have a 1:1 mapping between bytes and characters.  You may need to read chunks of the file in binary mode and do the translation to characters from the buffer.

Once you have the log file entries parsed then you can just insert the data, or use SQLBulkCopy for larger data volumes.

If you can relax your latency constraints and the log file is small enough then you could possibly just implement a process that copies the log file to a staging area and reloads the whole thing periodically.

Answer (score 0):

How about an SSIS package being called by an SQL Server Scheduled Job?